# Sidekiq does not show logs from other classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, sidekiq

Why log message from User class does not show up in Sidekiq log window?

**expenses_worker.rb**

```
class ExpensesWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform
      logger.info "I am called from worker" #<-- it is visible in Sidekiq!
      User.do_stuff
    end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.do_stuff
    logger.info "I am doing stuff"  #<-- it is NOT visible in Sidekiq...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your app has them set up as two separate loggers with different destinations.

Comment: I have a separate console window running sidekiq process. In that window when ExpensesWorker is running I can see its log message, but I can not understand why I can not see a log message from User.do_stuff which is called inside `perform` method...

Comment: What do I need to change in my app so I could see log messages from User class?